# How to conditionally set font-size on Sass depending on string length

Tags: css, string, if-statement, sass, font-size

I want to conditionally set the font-size of a div depending of the string length with Scss.

Something like this:

if id.length > 30
id.style.fontSize = 2vw

Comment: I don't believe SASS or any CSS-based tool can work out that sort of computation without 
being accompanied by JavaScript.

Comment: If you have the string hardcoded, you can do something like this. https://wikimass.com/sass/str-length with https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if however, if we're talking user inputs and things like that, then I don't believe it's possible without JavaScript.

Comment: Yes I've seen that, but I don't really know how to use it exactly. But i'm pretty sure it is possible. This is strings from a nextjs app. I found a way to do it with js but I guess that it is possible to do it with sass it's even better ``